# Vector of function pointers to different classes

Tags: c++, vector, interface, function-pointers

I have a typedef of a function pointer:

```
typedef int(interface1::*getInfoInterface1_t)(void);
```

Then a vector of these function pointers:

```
std::vector<getInfoInterface1_t>
```

I'd like to reuse this class I've created, but each instance implements a different virtual interface class.  If the class doesn't match, the pointer will have a mismatch.

Since I haven't been able to figure this out, I unfortunately made an exact copy of this class, identical except for the typedef and the vector.

It'd be nice to be able to have different function signatures, as well.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: You might want to read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Comment: Namespace don't matter here. Do you mean to pointers to members of different classes?

Comment: @Barry - yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a class template where the class you're keeping pointers to is a template argument:

```
template  <typename Cls>
class Foo {
    typedef int(Cls::*getInfoInterface1_t)(void);
    std::vector<getInfoInterface1_t> ifcs;
    // ...
};
```

That way, for each class type, you just choose the right template:

```
Foo<interface1> your_original_version;
```